# Read Excel Macro without interop

Tags: c#

I need to get Excel macro and store into Object in C# , As we know with help of Interop excel we can do.

But I need to copy Excel macro without Interop reference .

Can you please assist ??

Comment: You can't.  The Interop uses a Microsoft Proprietary format.  You would have to manually save the macro in excel of write a VBA macro in Excel.

Comment: Thank for reply
But i don't need to write a macro, .xlsm file have the macro and I need to read it only with out Interop .

Thanks

Comment: You can right click on the macro in the vba explorer and export which create a vba extension which is text.  But not from c# which is the way you labeled the posting.

Comment: Thanks 
But I need to copy excel Macro in C# without using Interop ?

Comment: You cannot to it!!!

Comment: i think we can use compound doc but not sure How?

Comment: What is Compound Doc?  Is it just an application that is using the Interop?